# pyramid pserve pviews P* re.compile syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

I used to launch the command `pserve --reload development.ini` in my vagrant box to launch a pyramid server locally. The command was working until the last few days.

However, I now have a syntax error preventing me from launching pserve with or *without* conf file.

```
(py32)vagrant.vm bin # pserve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/bin/pserve", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 519, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2630, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2310, in load
return self.resolve()
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
   File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 31, in <module>
from pyramid.paster import setup_logging
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/paster.py", line 10, in <module>
from pyramid.scripting import prepare
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripting.py", line 1, in <module>
from pyramid.config import global_registries
File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from webob.exc import WSGIHTTPException as WebobWSGIHTTPException
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/webob/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from webob.request import *
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 10, in <module>
import simplejson as json
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
from .encoder import JSONEncoder, JSONEncoderForHTML
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 22
ESCAPE = re.compile(u'[\\x00-\\x1f\\\\"\\b\\f\\n\\r\\t\u2028\u2029]')
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use python 3.2.3 in this virtualenv

pviews and proutes give the same error

Any help appreciated :)

Regards

==========================

Thanks to Steve Piercy I uninstalled simplejson and pserve now works launched alone! Thanks again.

However, when I launch pserve development.ini, I now have another error:

```
(py32)vagrant.vm app # pserve --reload development.ini
Starting subprocess with file monitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/bin/pserve", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 51, in main
return command.run()
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 316, in run
global_conf=vars)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 340, in loadapp
return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
return context.create()
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/var/www/app/app/__init__.py", line 63, in main
request_factory=RequestFactory,
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 301, in __init__
exceptionresponse_view=exceptionresponse_view,
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 412, in setup_registry
self.include(inc)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 755, in include
c(configurator)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py", line 468, in includeme
_get_or_build_default_environment(config.registry)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py", line 309, in _get_or_build_default_environment
filters = parse_config(settings.get('jinja2.filters', ''))
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py", line 62, in parse_config
result[name.strip()] = maybe_import_string(impl)
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py", line 44, in maybe_import_string
return import_string(val.strip())
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 213, in import_string
return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
  File "/var/www/app/app/views/filters.py", line 1, in <module>
from babel.dates import format_datetime, get_timezone, format_timedelta, format_date, UTC
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 436, in load_module
return self._load_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 141, in decorated
return fxn(self, module, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 342, in _load_module
exec(code_object, module.__dict__)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-z2s2e9/babel/babel/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "/var/virtualenv/py32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/babel/core.py", line 394
retval += ' (%s)' % u', '.join(details)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to uninstall-reinstall babel with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: u'somestring' is a Python 2 syntax (see the last line in the traceback). Before Python 3.3 it was considered a syntax error in Python 3. Probably because of that Babel requires Python 3.3 and up - you seem to be using 3.2  http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/dev.html#python-versions

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently install simplejson?  It was and never will be compatible with Python 3.0 - 3.2.  See https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/issues/66#issuecomment-15360824

Comment: Thank you. It resolved the issue with no parameters. However still got issues with parameters (see edit)

Comment: Python 3.2 was end-of-lifed in February 2016. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0392/#lifespan I recommend upgrading to a more current and maintained version of Python, unless you absolutely must use 3.2.

Comment: Additionally Pyramid has its current stable latest release version as [1.6.1](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/) with a final [1.7 release](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.7-branch/) coming soon.